# How to solve the PROXY ERROR while creating new app in IONIC?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

**E:\companies>ionic start myapk**

Pick a framework!

Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply a value for the
--type option.

**? Framework: Angular**

**Let's pick the perfect starter template!**

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything you need to build your app. To bypass thisprompt next time, supply template, the second argument to ionic start.

**? Starter template: tabs**
√ Preparing directory .\myapk - done!

| Downloading and extracting tabs starter

**[ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?**

**If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80**

**/ Downloading and extracting tabs starter**

I'm facing the above issue to create a new app in ionic, it has been stuck by throwing this error, I have tried many settings for proxy but not worked.

**I'm using the latest version of @ionic/cli i.e 6.11.0 & my node version is v12.16.3**

Please Help me get out of this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and using VPN worked for me
hope using vpn solve the problem for You